# Does block_collapse() in sympy fail on inverse-transpose of a block matrix?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I'm trying to perform some routine linear algebra on symbolic block matrices using `sympy`. When I call `block_collapse()` on a matrix that has been inversed and then transposed (in that order), `block_collapse()` outputs `1` instead of the correct matrix. See the last example of this reprex

```py
from sympy import (BlockMatrix, symbols, Identity, ZeroMatrix, block_collapse)
n = symbols('n')
In = Identity(n)
Zeron = ZeroMatrix(n,n)
A = BlockMatrix([
  [In, Zeron],
  [Zeron, In]])
At = A.transpose()
Ati = At.inverse()
Ai = A.inverse()
Ait = Ai.transpose()

block_collapse(A)
# Matrix([
# [I, 0],
# [0, I]])
block_collapse(At)
# Matrix([
# [I, 0],
# [0, I]])
block_collapse(Ati)
# Matrix([
# [I, 0],
# [0, I]])
block_collapse(Ai)
# Matrix([
# [I, 0],
# [0, I]])
block_collapse(Ait) # This one fails
# 1
```

On the other hand, manually calling `block_collapse()` on the intermediate matrix seems to resolve the problem and give the correct output.

```py
Aib = block_collapse(Ai)
Aibt = Aib.transpose()
block_collapse(Aibt)
# Matrix([
# [I, 0],
# [0, I]])
```

Have I misunderstood something about how `block_collapse` is meant to work, or is this a bug?

Comment: Look at the `type` of the expressions.  `Ait` is a `MatPow`, while the others are `BlockMatrix` or `Inverse`.

Comment: @hpaulj that's a good observation, although `block_collapse()` works on other `MatPow` matrices. Eg, `block_collapse(sqrt(A))` correctly returns a matrix (albeit `sympy` doesn't know how to simplify it).

Comment: This is a bug. Please report to github: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: Posted to github here: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/24735